# How to Properly shutdown and disassemble SQL Database Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

While testing SQL Server Replication we setup Replication on our ERP Test DB from SQL Server Enterprise to SQL Server Standard.

We have since got replication up-and-running on our Live database and we no longer need replication on the Test database...

We would like to PROPERLY remove the replication to free up resources and delete the Test Replicated DB.

I  have read online about issues with not properly 'disassembling' or shutting down Replication but I have not been able to find a step by step on how to do it.

I just have one test DB that is replicating between these servers that I need to shutdown and remove completely.

Specifics:

> SQL 2012, 1 DB, Transactional Replication.

Answer (score 1):

To properly clean up replication, follow below steps :

1. Open SSMS --> Local Publications --> Expand Publication -->

   [image]

   [image]

   2. Use [`sp_removedbreplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188734.aspx) to remove replication bit set on database.

Another Method is script our the DROP or disable the components by right click on publication and then run that script using SSMS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I ran those steps but do I need to delete the empty Publication node?  Also, my Replication Monitor has an error on the Test DB Log Reader... obviously.
This makes me think there is more to this.